# Maven - Eclipse - Project I am trying to add an image to database , The image doesn't appear in my JSP page until i refresh the image

Tags: eclipse, image, maven

This is the Controller page in which i have added my Image Upload Section . 
When I add the product image to my database using a multi-part file and when i am listing it , the product thumbnail appears , once i refresh the resources - only then the image is displayed when i list it . 
let me know what i should do .

```
@RequestMapping(value="/saveProd", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView gotoSave(@ModelAttribute("prod")Product prod,ModelMap m, Model a)
 {
     MultipartFile file = prod.getFile();
     String fileName = "";

     String image="";
     if(!file.isEmpty())
     {
          try
          { 
              System.out.println("inside try");
        fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();
        byte[] filesize=file.getBytes();
        BufferedOutputStream bout=new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("\\C:\\Users\\GOOD\\workspace\\fionazcosmetics\\src\\main\\webapp\\resources\\images\\" + fileName)));
        bout.write(filesize);
        bout.close();
        image="/resources/images/"+fileName;
        //r.setAttribute("img" ,image);
        m.addAttribute("img", image);
        System.out.println("upload sucess.."+image);

          }
          catch (IOException e) {
              System.out.println("upload failed..");
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
     }
     List<Supplier> x = supplierservice.getList();
     a.addAttribute("sList",x);
     List<Category> abc = categoryservice.getList();
     a.addAttribute("cList",abc);
     productDAOservice.insertRow(prod,image);
     List ls=productDAOservice.getList();
     return new ModelAndView("productadd","listProd",ls);
     }
```